# How to create outputs in columns using Printf with varied output lengths - Java

Tags: java, string, eclipse, printf

I was asked to create a code with three methods. This program should be have a method for each of the conversions decimalToBinary, decimalToOctal and decimalToHexadecimal and then display the results in a table with four columns: Decimal, Binary, Octal and Hexadecimal using printf

I was able to create the code to do the conversions however I am having a very hard time figuring out how to print the code into a column. I did research and I know how to use printf however I am confused since the lengths of the outputs will be different every time. How can I get them to display equally? Here is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Convert {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter your decimal number");

    int decimal = input.nextInt();
    System.out.printf("Decimal: %d\n", decimal);

    String binary=decimalToBinary(decimal);
    System.out.printf("Binary: %s\n", binary);

    String octa=decimalToOctal(decimal);
    System.out.printf("Octal: %s\n", octa);


    String hexa=decimalToOctal(decimal);
    System.out.printf("Hexa:%s\n", hexa);


}

public static String decimalToBinary(int decimal) {

    int remainder;
    String answer="";

    while (decimal>0) {
    remainder=decimal%2;
    decimal=decimal/2;
    answer=remainder+answer;

    }
    return answer;
```

}

```
public static String decimalToOctal(int decimal) {

    int remainder;
    String answer="";

    while (decimal>0) {
    remainder=decimal%8;
    decimal=decimal/8;
    answer=remainder+answer;    
    }
    return answer;
}

public static String decimalToHexadecimal(int decimal) {

    int remainder;
    String answer="";


    while (decimal>0) {
        remainder=decimal%16;
        decimal=decimal/16;

        if (remainder==10)
            answer= "A" + answer;
        else if (remainder==11)
            answer= "B" + answer;
        else if (remainder==12)
            answer= "C" + answer;
        else if (remainder==13)
            answer= "D" + answer;
        else if (remainder==14)
            answer= "E" + answer;
        else if (remainder==15)
            answer= "F" + answer;
        else answer=remainder+answer;
    }
    return answer;

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [printf() documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-), in particular the [format string syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax). You are after the width specifiers. For example,

```
printf("%20s", s);
```

will ensure your output will have a width of 20 characters. You can play around with the variations to achieve what you want.

Comment: I had tried different lengths, I just left the lengths out when I pasted my code because I realized the problem is even if I put 20 characters, or 15, or any it goes out of line with different inputs as some inputs will create longer outputs.

Comment: For example, this code works if the user input is "30"
  
  System.out.println("Please enter your decimal number");
  
  int decimal = input.nextInt();
  System.out.printf("Decimal: %20d\n", decimal);
  
  String binary=decimalToBinary(decimal);
  System.out.printf("Binary: %21s\n", binary);
  
  String octa=decimalToOctal(decimal);
  System.out.printf("Octal: %22s\n", octa);
  
  
  String hexa=decimalToOctal(decimal);
  System.out.printf("Hexa:%24s\n", hexa);


Any other input its not inline